# jScrollPane in Firefox - Dragger fills entire bar and doesn't scroll

Tags: firefox, jscrollpane

My jScrollPane (division) works well in IE and Chrome. *It may be of some significance that I am also running JQuery MouseScroll and hoverintent*. Again, these functions work fine in IE and Chrome.

---

The division is displayed properly in Firefox, as is the vertical scrollbar. There's about 50 lines to scroll down through.

In Firefox, the dragger fills the entire length of the vertical bar and doesn't move. The dragger and the arrows do respond to mouseover, but the functions don't work.

**Perhaps the scrolling action is functional**, just that there is no space to scroll, because the dragger fills the entire region. I am unsure whether my jScrollPane works or doesn't in Opera or Safari.

I checked Google and found little directly associated advice, just to:

> "Ensure that the division has a height specified (it does) and to try refreshing (no luck) in case the content (only text) needs to pre-load."

I wonder whether anyone can suggest any checks for me to make from their previous experience before I post any code to wade through.

---

This is only the second question tagged with jScrollPane & Firefox, so perhaps no-one will be familiar with this 'bug'. In which case I will create and post some reduced code which generates this bug in Firefox but not IE or Chrome.

---

Update: I created a 'test' scrollbar webpage to see if the bug would be replicated, and that works fine - so no need to post that for error-checking.

---

The problem must lie somewhere within my code on the site I'm working on.

So far I have identified that all the JavaScripts work and my custom jScrollPane CSS is fine. So it's just a process of elimination through each of the stylesheets now. I have a feeling the source of the bug may be in my custom reset CSS.

I'm confident I'll fix the bug, and will let you folks know either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug was in the CSS reset as suspected. Specifically, with the rule for column-count.

I had defined them (moz-/wekbit-/column-count) as '1' instead of the defining as 'auto' / not defining it at all.

This was from when I was experimenting with (CSS3) multi-column text. Presumably jScrollPane requires multiple columns. Not enough support yet for multi-column text to be worth implementing yet IMO.